# Rails 4.2 / PostgreSQL and Test Database Preparation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

We are using `Rake::Task['db:create'].enhance` to add a new schema and create an extension in the newly created schema as below.

```
Rake::Task['db:create'].enhance do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS shared_extensions;')
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" SCHEMA shared_extensions;')
end
```

Can we enhance the test database preparation in the same way?

Comment: Have you tried use `rake db:create:all` it is create all databases in the config `database.yml`?

Comment: I tried rake db:create:all. The strange thing is, db:create will invoke on development database whereas db:create:all will not. It did not create the schema 'shared_extensions' in development, test and production databases.

Comment: i think about another way, try specify `RAILS_ENV=test`  when you run you rake task.

Comment: `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test` will create the 'shared_extensions' schema and enable the uuid-ossp extension. I am wondering how to automate this with RSpec and Database Cleaner.

Comment: Why you need automate this for `RSpec` and `Database Cleaner` if that task already create your test env once, or you want recreate all for each test run? if yes then this should be really slow test assertions.

Comment: You are right. I will give a try on the multitenant system I am building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for this in Wiki for apartment gem.

```
Rake::Task["db:test:purge"].enhance do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS shared_extensions;')
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" SCHEMA shared_extensions;')
end
```